I need a dropdown background image for select tag in dark mode
I couldn't find a dropdown image with light color
I'm using the below url as the dropdown image in select tag in Tailwind CSS. When I switch to the dark mode, the image appears the same. I couldn't find any dropdown with light color. Is there any image with light color or should I change my approach?
backgroundImage:{
"arrow":"url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAB4AAAAUCAMAAACtdX32AAAAdVBMVEUAAAD///8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAhMdQaAAAAJ3RSTlMAAAECAwQGBwsOFBwkJTg5RUZ4eYCHkJefpaytrsXGy8zW3+Do8vNn0bsyAAAAYElEQVR42tXROwJDQAAA0Ymw1p9kiT+L5P5HVEi3qJn2lcPjtIuzUIJ/rhIGy762N3XaThqMN1ZPALsZPEzG1x8LrFL77DHBnEMxBewz0fJ6LyFHTPL7xhwzWYrJ9z22AqmQBV757MHfAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC)"
}
